# HttpServletRequest redirect with nginx

Tags: servlets, redirect, nginx

I have an servlet application which is deployed in a private network on port `8080`, and we use the nginx which can be accessed outside to proxy that:

The proxy machine have two network cards:

```
192.168.10.12(can be accessed outside)
10.1.1.2(private,can not be accessed)
```

And the nginx configuration:

```
server {
    listen       88;
    server_name  192.168.10.12;
    location ~ /server/ {
        proxy_pass   http://10.1.1.2:8080;
    }
}
```

Everything works well until it meet the `redirect`, the following response may be send to the client:
    response.sendRedirect("/login");

Then the browser will try to get `http://10.1.1.2/login`, which can be be accessed.

While I want the browser redirect to `http://192.168.10.12:88/login`.

Is this possible?

Comment: Which backend server you are using?

Answer (score 0):

The host name in sendRedirect() method should use :

- The server name itself when there is no proxy.
- The proxy name which redirected the request.

The second can be achieved by configuring RemoteIpValve for Tomcat.

The RemoteIpValve configuration looks like this:

> ```
> <Valve
>   className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve"
>    internalProxies="192\.168\.0\.10|192\.168\.0\.11"
>    remoteIpHeader="x-forwarded-for"
>    proxiesHeader="x-forwarded-by"
>    trustedProxies="proxy1|proxy2"
>  />
> ```

Read [Configuring RemoteIpValue](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/valves/RemoteIpValve.html)

Comment: As said the backend application is served by tomcat.